# Java generic method erasure and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-safety

I am running into a problem with javas generics and overriding methods. Imagine I have a deep tree-like class hierarchy. The top-level class defines a method foo which takes 1 argument of type Strategy. Strategy has a generic type parameter.

Each class in my class hierarchy needs to override foo to limit the kind of Strategy it can be passed so that the generic type parameter of the strategy matches the declaring class. Below is an example:

```
abstract static class TopLevelClass {

    static final Strategy<TopLevelClass> s1 = tlc -> System.out.println(tlc.getTopLevelAtt());

    String getTopLevelAtt() {
        return "TopLevelAtt";
    }

    void foo(Strategy<TopLevelClass> s) {s.bar(this);}
}
static class MidLevelClass extends TopLevelClass {

    static final Strategy<MidLevelClass> s2 = mlc -> System.out.println(mlc.getMidLevelAtt());

    String getMidLevelAtt() {
        return "MidLevelAtt";
    }

    void foo(Strategy<MidLevelClass> s) {s.bar(this);}
}
static class LowLevelClass extends MidLevelClass  {

    static final Strategy<LowLevelClass> s3 = llc -> System.out.println(llc.getTopLevelAtt());

    String getLowLevelAtt() {
        return "LowLevelAtt";
    }

    void foo(Strategy<LowLevelClass> s) {s.bar(this);}
}
static interface Strategy<X> {
    void bar(X x);
}
```

In this example I want to be able to call foo on instances of class LowLevelClass with any of the static references s1, s2 and s3 defined in TopLevelClass, MidLevelClass and LowLevelClass respectively. Ideally I would not have to call different methods foo1, foo2 or foo3 depending on the argument.

The code above does *NOT* compile in java. The compile-time-error is:

> Name clash: The method foo(Strategy) of type MidLevelClass  has the same erasure as foo(Strategy) of type TopLevelClass  but does not override it

I doubt this can easily be resolved. I could just use raw-types and rely on run-time typechecks but I would rather keep type safety. What can I do to achieve this without sacrificing the type hierarchy or type safety? Please note that passing the Strategy in the constructor *IS NOT* an option for me! It must be possible to call foo multiple times over the life time of the object.

### Edit:

I realize, that this problem is perhaps difficult to follow without knowing the circumstances surrounding it. I have opened a more detailed question explaining the background of my problem here: [How to make this Strategy-Object pattern type safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028518/how-to-make-this-strategy-object-pattern-type-safe)

Comment: I think you're over-encapsulating `Strategy`; as it is now your strategy is tied specifically to what object you're calling it on. And you simply pass back the object you're calling the method on. It's pretty much a waste at that point. What are you trying to achieve with the actual background problem?

Comment: I will use this for a high-level event -> action system for a UI framework. The Strategy inteface is a stand-in for actions to be taken in reaction to Key inputs, mouse movements, drag-n-drop, copy-n-paste, etc events. For example TopLevelClass would be some kind of abstract widget. MidLevelClass would be a collection component with Copy and selection actions. LowLevelClass would be a list with arrow key movement actions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about erasure then just use separate method names for separate methods:

```
abstract class TopLevelClass {
    void fooTop(Strategy<TopLevelClass> s) {/*...*/}
}
class MidLevelClass extends TopLevelClass {
    void fooMid(Strategy<MidLevelClass> s) {/*...*/}
}
class LowLevelClass extends MidLevelClass  {
    void fooLow(Strategy<LowLevelClass> s) {/*...*/}
}
```

However, I suspect **erasure is not your problem**. You presumably want to override the same method.

An instance of `Strategy<LowLevelClass>` cannot possibly be a `Strategy<MidLevelClass>`, which cannot be a Strategy;

Given

```
Strategy<LowLevelClass> l;
Strategy<MidLevelClass> m;
```

Then you cannot assign one to another.

```
l = m; // Compile-time fail.
m = l; // Compile-time fail.
```

And therefore it would make no sense to be able to do the same via method overriding. (It's also always been true that `bar(TopLevelClass)` cannot override `bar(MidLevelClass)`, though since 1.5 there are covariant return types.)

Add a type parameter to the class to use as a type argument in the method.

```
abstract class TopLevelClass<T extends TopLevelClass<T>> {
    void foo(Strategy<T> s) {/*...*/}
}
class MidLevelClass<T extends MidLevelClass<T>> extends TopLevelClass<T> {
    void foo(Strategy<T> s) {/*...*/}
}
class LowLevelClass<T extends LowLevelClass<T>> extends MidLevelClass<T>  {
    void foo(Strategy<T> s) {/*...*/}
}
```

The updated question add the use of `this` as a argument to a call of `Strategy.foo`. This implies `MidLevelClass` must be `abstract` - it cannot guarantee `foo` is overridden. The type of `this` now needs to fit the type parameter. To do that, add an `abstract` *"getThis"* method (concrete in concrete subclasses).

```
    protected abstract X getThis();
...
    @Override protected X getThis() { return this; }
```

The type of the `static` fields requires wildcards:

```
static final Strategy<? extends TopLevelClass<?>> s1 =
    tlc -> System.out.println(tlc.getTopLevelAtt());
```

*(Better designs prefer composition over inheritance.)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I realized my question was not detailed enough. Please review the edit I made to my question to see why your solutions do not work for my case.

Comment: Thanks for responding to this question again. I had considered your solution before but found it inadequate for my needs. The main reason is how large declarations become with the generic type parameters. In practice this often leads to users just sacrificing type-safety in favor of brevity. Please see my expanded question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028518/how-to-make-this-strategy-object-pattern-type-safe

Answer (score 1):

I feel that there a couple of difficulties with this design:

1. Since each of your class implements its own `Strategy` using only methods within the same class, there is no need for `Strategy.bar()` to take an instance of the class. This passing of parameter is one of the causes of the hindrance to implementing this neatly.
2. Since all the implementations of `foo()` are doing exactly the same thing, you don't need multiple implementations.

Here is a code that has a partial solution. Partial because, in a good solution, you should be able to pass the reference of `TopLevelClass` in the changed `foo()` method. If you can figure out a way for that, I think it will be just great. With this solution, the class hierarchy is not a factor since we are using specific reference types.

I have commented the changed parts starting "CHANGE".

```
public class Erasure1{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        LowLevelClass slc = new LowLevelClass(); //'slc' must be exactly the same type as the instance. This is a limitation with this solution. Ideal thing would have been that this reference be of type TopLevelClass.
        slc.foo( LowLevelClass.s3, slc );
    }

    abstract static class TopLevelClass{

        static final Strategy<TopLevelClass> s1 = tlc -> System.out.println( tlc.getTopLevelAtt() );

        String getTopLevelAtt(){ return "TopLevelAtt"; }

        /* CHANGE 1: It is necessary that the instance of TopLevelClass subtype be passed since 
         * Strategy.bar() doesn't accept wildcards. Changing it to accept a 'T' to pass to bar().
         * Also, since, this is now taking 'T' as a parameter, this method could very well be a 
         * static method in a utility class. */
        <T> void foo( Strategy<T> s, T tlc ){
            s.bar( tlc );
        }
    }

    static class MidLevelClass extends TopLevelClass{
        static final Strategy<MidLevelClass> s2 = mlc -> System.out.println(mlc.getMidLevelAtt());;

        String getMidLevelAtt(){ return "MidLevelAtt"; }

        /* CHANGE 2: Since this method is not doing anything different from its parent, this is not required. */
        //void foo(Strategy<MidLevelClass> s) {s.bar(this);}
    }

    static class LowLevelClass extends MidLevelClass{

        static final Strategy<LowLevelClass> s3 = llc -> System.out.println( llc.getLowLevelAtt() );

        String getLowLevelAtt(){ return "LowLevelAtt"; }

        /* CHANGE 2: Since this method is not doing anything different from its parent, this is not required. */
        //void foo(Strategy<LowLevelClass> s) {s.bar(this);}
    }

    static interface Strategy<X> {
        void bar( X x );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have opened another question with much more detail, explaining the circumstances surrounding this problem. Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028518/how-to-make-this-strategy-object-pattern-type-safe