# How to make this Strategy-Object pattern type safe

Tags: java, generics, strategy-pattern, type-safety

### This is the long version of a question I asked earlier

For the tl;dr version please see here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60026280/java-generic-method-erasure-and-inheritance/60028010#60028010)

I am sorry for this wall of text, but please bear with me. I put a lot of effort into the question and I believe the problem at hand should interesting to many here.

### Background

I am writing a UI Framework with a classic [Scene Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph). I have an abstract Top-Level class called *Component* and many subclasses, some of which are concrete while others abstract as well. A concrete subclass might be *Button* while an abstract subclass is *Collection*. The Mid-Level class *Collection* is the supertype for such classes as *ListView*, *TreeView* or *TableView* and contains common functionality that all of these subclasses share.

To promote good programming principles such as Single Responsibility, Separation of Concerns, etc, features of Components are implemented as [Strategy-Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). These can be added to and removed from components at runtime to manipulate their behaviour. See the example below:

```
public abstract class Collection extends Component {

    /**
     * A strategy that enables items within this Collection to be selected upon mouse click.
     */
    public static final Action<Collection, MouseClick> CLICK_ITEM_ACTION = 
            // this action can only be added to components for which Collection.class.isInstance(component) == true
            Action.FOR (Collection.class)
            // this action will only happen when a MouseClick event is delivered to the component
            .WHEN (MouseClick.class)
            // this condition must be true when the event happens
            .IF ((collection, mouseClickEvent) -> 
                collection.isEnabled() && collection.hasItemAt(mouseClickEvent.getPoint())
            )
            // these effects will happen as a reaction
            .DO ((collection, mouseClickEvent) -> 
                collection.setSelectedItem(collection.getItemAt(mouseClickEvent.getPoint()))
            )
    ;

    // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

}
```

The example is obviously heavily simplified but hopefully the meaning can be understood without seeing the implementations of the many methods used within.

Many instances of the *Action* are defined throughout the framework in the same way as above. This way the behaviour of each Component can be precisely controlled by developers using the framework.

A subclass of *Collection* is *ListView* which extends *Collection* by mapping integer indices to items in the collection. For a *ListView* it is possible to move the selection "up" and "down" by pressing the corresponding arrow keys on the keyboard. This feature is also implemented via the strategy pattern as an Action:

```
public class ListView extends Collection {

    /**
     * A strategy that enables the selection to be moved "up" (that is to an item with a lower index) 
     * upon pressing the UP arrow key.
     */
    static final Action<ListView, KeyPress> ARROW_UP_ACTION = 
        // this action can only be added to components for which ListView.class.isInstance(component) == true
        Action.FOR (ListView.class)
        // this action will only happen when a KeyPress event is delivered to the component
        .WHEN (KeyPress.class)
        // this condition must be true when the event happens
        .IF ((list, keyPressEvent) -> 
            keyPressEvent.getKey() == ARROW_UP && list.isEnabled() 
                && list.hasSelection() && list.getSelectedIndex() > 0
        )
        // these effects will happen as a reaction
        .DO ((list, keyPressEvent) -> 
            list.setSelectedIndex(list.getSelectedIndex() - 1)
        )
    ;

    // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

}
```

### Problem

These features so far **work as intended**. The problem arises with how these actions are registered at a component. My current idea was to have a method *registerAction* in the *Component* class:

```
public abstract class Component {

    public void registerAction(Object key, Action action) {
        // the action is mapped to the key (for reference) and 
        // "somehow" connected to the internal event propagation system
    }

    // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

}
```

As you can see, the **generic type parameters** of action are lost here and I have not found a way to introduce them in a meaningful way. This means that Actions can illegaly be added to components for which they are not defined. Take a look at this [driver class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765751/what-is-a-driver-class-java) for an example of the kind of error that can not be detected at compile-time right now:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListView personList = new ListView();

        // this is intended to be possible and is!
        personList.registerAction(
                Collection.CLICK_ITEM_KEY, 
                Collection.CLICK_ITEM_ACTION
        );
        personList.registerAction(
                ListView.ARROW_UP_KEY, 
                ListView.ARROW_UP_ACTION
        );

        // this is intended to be possible and is!
        personList.registerAction(
                "MyCustomAction",

                Action.FOR (Collection.class)
                .WHEN (MouseClick.class)
                .DO ((col, evt) -> System.out.println("List has been clicked at: " + evt.getPoint()))
        );

        // this will eventually result in a runtime ClassCastException 
        // but should ideally be detected at compile-time
        personList.registerAction(
                Button.PRESS_SPACE_KEY, 
                Button.PRESS_SPACE_ACTION
        );
    }

}
```

### What have I tried?

I made a few attempts to deal with / improve the situation:

1. Try to overwrite the *registerAction* method in each subclass of *Component*. This will not work because of how generic type erasure is implemented in java. For more details refer to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60026280/java-generic-method-erasure-and-inheritance/60028010#60028010).
2. Introduce a generic type parameter to each subclass of *Component* which will always be identical to the type of Component. This same solution has been suggested as an [answer in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60026387/8458119). I don't like this solution because all declarations will become hugely overblown. I know that in practice this will lead to users just abandoning the type safety entirely because they prefer readability over type safety. So although this is technically a solution it will not work for my users.
3. Just ignore it. This is the obvious Plan B if all else fails. In this case runtime type checking is all that can be done.

I am open to any suggestions, even those that require a major overhaul of the architecture. The only requirements are, that no functionality is lost and working with the framework is still simple enough without declarations becoming overburdened with generics.

### Edit

Here is the Code for the Action class and code for the Events that can be used to compile and test the code:

```
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;

public class Action<C extends Component, E extends Event> {

    private final Class<E> eventType;
    private final BiPredicate<C, E> condition;
    private final BiConsumer<C, E> effect;

    public Action(Class<E> eventType, BiPredicate<C, E> condition, BiConsumer<C, E> effect) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.condition = condition;
        this.effect = effect;
    }

    public void onEvent(C component, Event event) {
        if (eventType.isInstance(event)) {
            E evt = (E) event;
            if (condition == null || condition.test(component, evt)) {
                effect.accept(component, evt);
            }
        }
    }

    private static final Impl impl = new Impl();
    public static <C extends Component> DefineEvent<C> FOR(Class<C> componentType) {
        impl.eventType = null;
        impl.condition = null;
        return impl;
    }

    private static class Impl implements DefineEvent, DefineCondition, DefineEffect {
        private Class eventType;
        private BiPredicate condition;
        public DefineCondition WHEN(Class eventType) {
            this.eventType = eventType;
            return this;
        }
        public DefineEffect IF(BiPredicate condition) {
            this.condition = condition;
            return this;
        }
        public Action DO(BiConsumer effect) {
            return new Action(eventType, condition, effect);
        }
    }
    public static interface DefineEvent<C extends Component> {
        <E extends Event> DefineCondition<C, E> WHEN(Class<E> eventType);
    }
    public static interface DefineCondition<C extends Component, E extends Event>  {
        DefineEffect<C, E> IF(BiPredicate<C, E> condition);
        Action<C, E> DO(BiConsumer<C, E> effects);
    }
    public static interface DefineEffect<C extends Component, E extends Event> {
        Action<C, E> DO(BiConsumer<C, E> effect);
    }
}

public class Event {

    public static final Key ARROW_UP = new Key();
    public static final Key SPACE = new Key();

    public static class Point {}
    public static class Key {}
    public static class MouseClick extends Event {
        public Point getPoint() {return null;}
    }
    public static class KeyPress extends Event {
        public Key getKey() {return null;}
    }
    public static class KeyRelease extends Event {
        public Key getKey() {return null;}
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please also add a minimal code for the ```Action``` class? Then we can try out the code.

Comment: done; see the edit. Please note that these are also heavily abbreviated for the purpose of this thread.

Comment: Are the actions registered in a global registry, which is only one, or does each ```Component``` subtype instance keep its own map of registered ```Action```s?

Comment: The components keep a local map of actions but the actions are, depending on circumstances, also registered in a "global" event propagation system. It is complicated but the specifics should not be important for the strategy pattern at use here.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but try as I might, I could not figure out any issue with your code except that your `registerAction()` method's `Action` parameter may take wildcard instead of being non-generic. Wildcard is OK, since no one can define something like `Action<String,Object>` anyhow due to the restrictions already posed in the type parameters of `Action` class.

Have a look at the change below. I have just added a `static Map<>` to hold the registered items and adding to it in `registerAction()`. I don't see why this method should be a problem at all.

```
public static abstract class Component{
    /* Just as a sample of the registry of actions. */
    private static final Map<Object, Action<?,?>> REGD = new HashMap<>();

    public void registerAction(Object key, Action<?,?> action) {
        // the action is mapped to the key (for reference) and 
        // "somehow" connected to the internal event propagation system
        REGD.put( key, action );
    }

    /* Just to test. */
    public static Map<Object, Action<?, ?>> getRegd(){ return REGD; }

    // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

}
```

Comment: Because it allows you to add actions for Buttons to a ViewList which will result in a ClassCastException at runtime. Something that should not be happening in a strongly typed language.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes I brought in to make this happen. Please tell me if this works for you.

**1.** Change `Component` class to this. I have explained the changes after its code.

```
public static abstract class Component<T extends Component<?>>{
    Class<? extends T> type;

    Component( Class<? extends T> type ){
        this.type = type;
    }

    private Map<Object, Action<?,?>> REGD = new HashMap<>();

    public void registerAction(Object key, Action<? super T,?> action) {
        // the action is mapped to the key (for reference) and 
        // "somehow" connected to the internal event propagation system
        REGD.put( key, action );
    }

    public Map<Object, Action<?, ?>> getRegd(){ return REGD; }

    // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

}
```

Note the following changes:

1. Introduced a generic type to know which type a `Component` instance represents.
2. Made the subtypes declare their exact type on creation by adding a constructor that takes the `Class` instance of their type.
3. `registerAction()` accepts `Action<? super T>` only. That is, for `ListView`, an action that is on `ListView` or `Collection` is accepted but not of `Button`.

**2.** So, `Button` class now looks like this:

```
public static class Button extends Component<Button>{
    Button(){
        super( Button.class );
    }

    public static final Object PRESS_SPACE_KEY = "";
    public static final Action<Button, ?> PRESS_SPACE_ACTION = Action.FOR (Button.class)
            .WHEN (MouseClick.class)
            .DO ((col, evt) -> System.out.println("List has been clicked at: " + evt.getPoint()));

}
```

**3.** And the `Collection` being another class designed for extension, declares a similar constructor, which `ListView` implements.

```
public static abstract class Collection<T extends Collection> extends Component<T>{
    Collection( Class<T> type ){
        super( type );
    }

    public static final Object CLICK_ITEM_KEY = "CLICK_ITEM_KEY";
    /**
     * A strategy that enables items within this Collection to be selected upon mouse click.
     */
    public static final Action<Collection, Event.MouseClick> CLICK_ITEM_ACTION = 
            // this action can only be added to components for which Collection.class.isInstance(component) == true
            Action.FOR (Collection.class)
            // this action will only happen when a MouseClick event is delivered to the component
            .WHEN (Event.MouseClick.class)
            // this condition must be true when the event happens
            .IF ((collection, mouseClickEvent) -> 
                true //collection.isEnabled() && collection.hasItemAt(mouseClickEvent.getPoint())
            )
            // these effects will happen as a reaction
            .DO ((collection, mouseClickEvent) -> {}
                //collection.setSelectedItem(collection.getItemAt(mouseClickEvent.getPoint()))
            )
    ;

    // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

}

public static class ListView extends Collection<ListView> {

    ListView(){
        super( ListView.class );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static final Object ARROW_UP_KEY = "ARROW_UP_KEY";

    /**
     * A strategy that enables the selection to be moved "up" (that is to an item with a lower index) 
     * upon pressing the UP arrow key.
     */
    static final Action<ListView, Event.KeyPress> ARROW_UP_ACTION = 
        // this action can only be added to components for which ListView.class.isInstance(component) == true
        Action.FOR (ListView.class)
        // this action will only happen when a KeyPress event is delivered to the component
        .WHEN (Event.KeyPress.class)
        // this condition must be true when the event happens
        .IF ((list, keyPressEvent) -> true
                    /*keyPressEvent.getKey() == Event.ARROW_UP && list.isEnabled() 
                        && list.hasSelection() && list.getSelectedIndex() > 0*/
        )
        // these effects will happen as a reaction
        .DO ((list, keyPressEvent) -> 
            {} //list.setSelectedIndex(list.getSelectedIndex() - 1)
        )
    ;

    // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

}
```

**4.** Correspondingly, the `Action` class declaration changes to `class Action<C extends Component<?>, E extends Event>`.

---

---

The entire code as inner classes of another class, for easier analysis on your IDE.

```
public class Erasure2{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        ListView personList = new ListView();

        // this is intended to be possible and is!
        personList.registerAction(
                Collection.CLICK_ITEM_KEY, 
                Collection.CLICK_ITEM_ACTION
        );

        personList.registerAction(
                ListView.ARROW_UP_KEY, 
                ListView.ARROW_UP_ACTION
        );

        // this is intended to be possible and is!
        personList.registerAction(
                "MyCustomAction",

                Action.FOR (Collection.class)
                .WHEN (MouseClick.class)
                .DO ((col, evt) -> System.out.println("List has been clicked at: " + evt.getPoint()))
        );

        // this will eventually result in a runtime ClassCastException 
        // but should ideally be detected at compile-time
        personList.registerAction(
                Button.PRESS_SPACE_KEY, 
                Button.PRESS_SPACE_ACTION
        );

        personList.getRegd().forEach( (k,v) -> System.out.println( k + ": " + v ) );
    }

    public static abstract class Component<T extends Component<?>>{
        Class<? extends T> type;

        Component( Class<? extends T> type ){
            this.type = type;
        }

        private Map<Object, Action<?,?>> REGD = new HashMap<>();

        public void registerAction(Object key, Action<? super T,?> action) {
            // the action is mapped to the key (for reference) and 
            // "somehow" connected to the internal event propagation system
            REGD.put( key, action );
        }

        public Map<Object, Action<?, ?>> getRegd(){ return REGD; }

        // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

    }

    public static class Button extends Component<Button>{
        Button(){
            super( Button.class );
        }

        public static final Object PRESS_SPACE_KEY = "";
        public static final Action<Button, ?> PRESS_SPACE_ACTION = Action.FOR (Button.class)
                .WHEN (MouseClick.class)
                .DO ((col, evt) -> System.out.println("List has been clicked at: " + evt.getPoint()));

    }

    public static abstract class Collection<T extends Collection> extends Component<T>{
        Collection( Class<T> type ){
            super( type );
        }

        public static final Object CLICK_ITEM_KEY = "CLICK_ITEM_KEY";
        /**
         * A strategy that enables items within this Collection to be selected upon mouse click.
         */
        public static final Action<Collection, Event.MouseClick> CLICK_ITEM_ACTION = 
                // this action can only be added to components for which Collection.class.isInstance(component) == true
                Action.FOR (Collection.class)
                // this action will only happen when a MouseClick event is delivered to the component
                .WHEN (Event.MouseClick.class)
                // this condition must be true when the event happens
                .IF ((collection, mouseClickEvent) -> 
                    true //collection.isEnabled() && collection.hasItemAt(mouseClickEvent.getPoint())
                )
                // these effects will happen as a reaction
                .DO ((collection, mouseClickEvent) -> {}
                    //collection.setSelectedItem(collection.getItemAt(mouseClickEvent.getPoint()))
                )
        ;

        // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

    }

    public static class ListView extends Collection<ListView> {

        ListView(){
            super( ListView.class );
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public static final Object ARROW_UP_KEY = "ARROW_UP_KEY";

        /**
         * A strategy that enables the selection to be moved "up" (that is to an item with a lower index) 
         * upon pressing the UP arrow key.
         */
        static final Action<ListView, Event.KeyPress> ARROW_UP_ACTION = 
            // this action can only be added to components for which ListView.class.isInstance(component) == true
            Action.FOR (ListView.class)
            // this action will only happen when a KeyPress event is delivered to the component
            .WHEN (Event.KeyPress.class)
            // this condition must be true when the event happens
            .IF ((list, keyPressEvent) -> true
                        /*keyPressEvent.getKey() == Event.ARROW_UP && list.isEnabled() 
                            && list.hasSelection() && list.getSelectedIndex() > 0*/
            )
            // these effects will happen as a reaction
            .DO ((list, keyPressEvent) -> 
                {} //list.setSelectedIndex(list.getSelectedIndex() - 1)
            )
        ;

        // attributes, constructors & methods omitted for brevity.

    }

    public static class Action<C extends Component<?>, E extends Event> {

        private final Class<E> eventType;
        private final BiPredicate<C, E> condition;
        private final BiConsumer<C, E> effect;

        public Action(Class<E> eventType, BiPredicate<C, E> condition, BiConsumer<C, E> effect) {
            this.eventType = eventType;
            this.condition = condition;
            this.effect = effect;
        }

        public void onEvent(C component, Event event) {
            if (eventType.isInstance(event)) {
                E evt = (E) event;
                if (condition == null || condition.test(component, evt)) {
                    effect.accept(component, evt);
                }
            }
        }

        private static final Impl impl = new Impl();
        public static <C extends Component> DefineEvent<C> FOR(Class<C> componentType) {
            impl.eventType = null;
            impl.condition = null;
            return impl;
        }

        private static class Impl implements DefineEvent, DefineCondition, DefineEffect {
            private Class eventType;
            private BiPredicate condition;
            public DefineCondition WHEN(Class eventType) {
                this.eventType = eventType;
                return this;
            }
            public DefineEffect IF(BiPredicate condition) {
                this.condition = condition;
                return this;
            }
            public Action DO(BiConsumer effect) {
                return new Action(eventType, condition, effect);
            }
        }
        public static interface DefineEvent<C extends Component> {
            <E extends Event> DefineCondition<C, E> WHEN(Class<E> eventType);
        }
        public static interface DefineCondition<C extends Component, E extends Event>  {
            DefineEffect<C, E> IF(BiPredicate<C, E> condition);
            Action<C, E> DO(BiConsumer<C, E> effects);
        }
        public static interface DefineEffect<C extends Component, E extends Event> {
            Action<C, E> DO(BiConsumer<C, E> effect);
        }
    }

    public static class Event {

        public static final Key ARROW_UP = new Key();
        public static final Key SPACE = new Key();

        public static class Point {}
        public static class Key {}
        public static class MouseClick extends Event {
            public Point getPoint() {return null;}
        }
        public static class KeyPress extends Event {
            public Key getKey() {return null;}
        }
        public static class KeyRelease extends Event {
            public Key getKey() {return null;}
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There can be an improvement over this solution, where we don't need the child classes of ```Component``` to declare a constructor. That is by changing the constructor of ```Component``` to ```Component(){
    this.type = (Class<T>) this.getClass();
   }```. I haven't really thought of the consequences of this deeply though.